# Spring framework StoryBoard render Error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode-storyboard

I had a project working project.now I install the pod again

pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git', :branch => 'swift3'

No I am getting this error.

“error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for AvailabilityViewController no suitable image found. Did find: Spring.framework: required code signature missing for 'Spring.framework’ ”

Now my app is running.but I could not find views in story board.

I tried to remove all derived data from Xcode and I turn off Automatically manage signing.but nothing works. Hope you understand my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an issue related to new XCode and CocoaPods version 1.5

You can either

1. downgrade your CocoaPods to 1.4.x
2. Implement the following workaround: (add to the end of your podfile and do `pod update`

   `post_install do |installer|
       installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
           config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
       end
   end`

More info:
Official CocoaPods git issue:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606#issuecomment-381279098

Comment: Thanks a lot bro <3

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge on code signing, but can you submit to App Store after deleting 'CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED' and 'CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED' from build_settings?

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the correct solution to fix all IBDesignable issues.