# Xcode 9 : Failed to render and update Autolayout status for 'VC' T..s.framework: required code signature moving for 'TextFieldEffects.framework'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

my Xcode showing a strange issue in my storyboard I got the errors in Storyboard file. When I am running the project then there is no issue but when I open the storyboard file it gives me error showing in picture below. I follow this answer [XCode 8 - IB Designables - Failed to render and update auto layout status, The agent crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a) but it still showing the error. I am using Xcode 9.2. Any suggestion, how can I remove this error?[image]

Answer (score 2):

in my case i did that and worked for me (xcode 9.3)

1-downgrade your CocoaPods to 1.4.x from 1.5

2-add to the end of your podfile and do `pod update`

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
    config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
end
```

end

- see this question
  [Spring framework StoryBoard render Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767014/spring-framework-storyboard-render-error)
- More info: Official CocoaPods git issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606#issuecomment-381279098

Answer (score 2):

just delete the view that is failed and press command+Z to undo the deletion. It works for me.

The error may occur again, do the above again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting your **derived data**?

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

after deleting it clean the project and then Open your storyboard.

Go to **Editor > Refresh all views.**

Comment: Yes it did that I deleted the derived data and clear all views but it still showing the error. I followed the link step by step but no solution